# Chaning link method to delete with jquery, but still get post requests

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have very simple ajax votes counter with +/- to add/remove vote.

```
<div class="points pull-left">
  <a rel="nofollow" data-remote="true" data-method="post" href="/entry_votes?id=135">+</a>
  <span id="entry135">2</span>
</div>
```

When I click `+` it runs js for entry_votes view, changing span value( in this case to 3), changing `+` to `-`, `data-method` to `delete` and adding `class="unvote"`

It  works for below code:

create.js

```
$("#entry<%=@entry.id%>").html("<%=@entry.points_count%>")
$("#entry<%=@entry.id%>").siblings().replaceWith('<%= link_to "-",entry_vote_path(id: @entry.id),method: :delete, remote: true, class: "unvote"%>')
```

destroy.js

```
$("#entry<%=@entry.id%>").html("<%=@entry.points_count%>");
$("#entry<%=@entry.id%>").siblings().replaceWith('<%=link_to "+",entry_votes_path(id: @entry.id),method: :post,remote: true %>');
```

I don't want to replaceWith, but for both just toggle `data-method`, +/- and class = " " / "unvoted", so I wrote something like this:

create.js

```
$("#entry<%=@entry.id%>").html("<%=@entry.points_count%>")
$("#entry<%=@entry.id%>").siblings().attr("data-method","delete").addClass("unvote").html("-")
```

When I click it first time it works ok, changes all like I want. For example `+2` changes to `-3` and now when I click on `-` it still runs `create` action even though `data-method` is changed to delete. Any idea why?

Comment: Don't use `.html(…)` if what you mean is `.text(…)`; it is unsafe and slower.

Comment: If you have a nice css for both button and links, easiest way to fix this is just use `button_to` instead of `link_to` .

Comment: Can you show us the click handler for the link?